# What species cactus is this?

Tags: identification, cactus

I have taken a cutting from a large cactus, and it seems to propagate well. I was wondering what species it is? Does anyone know? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that's a Euphorbia, not a cactus. Similar to E. grandicornis. The tell is that the thorns aren't coming from an areole, they're growing from the edge of the plant.

All cactus are succulents, not all succulents are cactus.

Hopefully, a Euphorbia expert will chime in with an ID.

Comment: I think you are right about genus _Euphorbia_, I hope someone knows the species as well. Thank you also for explaining me that it is not a cactus!

Comment: Happy to help! Oh, Euphorbia sap is toxic to some degree, depending on species. Don't let kids or pets chew it and if you get sap on your hand DON'T touch your eyes!

Comment: While the "not all succulents are cacti" part of the mantra is correct, the first part is technically not. While most cacti are succulent, some are not, for example certain Pereskia species :)

Comment: In what way are Pereskia not succulent? Can you cite a reference?